# Get text from string with kotlin in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, module, getstring

I have a kotlin module with code like this.

```
class AppOpenManager(private val appLanding: AppLanding) : 
    Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, LifecycleObserver{

    //.........OTHER CODE

    companion object {
        private const val TEXT_HEADER = getString(R.string.textheader)
    }

    //.........OTHER CODE
    
}
```

However I can't get string resource from this code,

```
private const val TEXT_HEADER = getString(R.string.textheader)
```

string.xml :

```
<resources>
    <string name="textheader">Lorem Ipsum</string>
</resources>
```

Please help so I can fetch string values ​​into kotlin module from resources string.xml
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use applications context:

```
private const val TEXT_HEADER = 
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.textheader);
```

Comment: error, Unresolved reference: getApplicationContext

Comment: pass context in  `AppOpenManager(private val appLanding: AppLanding,private val context:Context) from activity`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `getString` like that outside Activity or Application you have to use like below.

```
context.getString(R.string.textheader)
```

So you have to have the context to refer to String from string.xml else you won't be able to access it.

Comment: I have error: Unresolved reference: getString

Comment: You used the `context.getString(R.string.textheader)` by having access to context where ever you were extracting the value?

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand how. I can extract the value from string.xml on "Main Activity.kt". Then I created a new kotlin module, but it can't do the same to extract the string.xml value in this module.

Comment: As i said you cannot use getString as it is outside of Activity or Application classes, you have to use `context.getString`